# auto field values in ndb.StructuredProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, endpoints-proto-datastore

I want to store locations in google's datastore. Each entry shall have got 'sys'-fields, which shall contain information set by the datastore.
I've got the class model below and the WebService JSON request/response looks ok, but I have to set the values manually. It looks like `auto_current_user_add`, `auto_now_add`, `auto_current_user` and `auto_now` does not trigger.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel


class Created(EndpointsModel):
    by = ndb.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True)
    on = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class Updated(EndpointsModel):
    by = ndb.UserProperty(auto_current_user=True)
    on = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)


class Sys(EndpointsModel):
    created = ndb.StructuredProperty(Created)
    updated = ndb.StructuredProperty(Updated)


class Location(EndpointsModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty()
    address = ndb.StringProperty()
    sys = ndb.StructuredProperty(Sys)
```

When I submit a create request (`location.put()`) I get the following response:

```
{
    "id": "4020001",
    "name": "asdf"
}
```

When I set it manually using:

```
location.sys = Sys(created=Created(on=datetime.datetime.now(),
                                   by=current_user),
                   updated=Updated(on=datetime.datetime.now(),
                                   by=current_user))
location.put()
```

I get the expected result:

```
{
 "id": "4020002",
 "name": "asdf",
 "sys": {
  "created": {
   "by": {
    "auth_domain": "gmail.com",
    "email": "decurgia@XYZ"
   },
   "on": "2015-01-27T16:05:41.465497"
  },
  "updated": {
   "by": {
    "auth_domain": "gmail.com",
    "email": "decurgia@XYZ"
   },
   "on": "2015-01-27T16:05:41.465577"
  }
 }
}
```

How can I get those fields (`sys.created.on`, `sys.created.by`, `sys.updated.on`, `sys.updated.by`) automatically set?

Answer (score 1):

In my limited work with `StructuredProperty`, I found it to be slower and more difficult to use than simply inserting the properties directly into the model.  NDB seems to store those properties separately and perform a "join" when retrieving them.  My recommendation is to use a "flat" model:

```
class Location(EndpointsModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty()
    address = ndb.StringProperty()
    created_by = ndb.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True)
    created_on = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by = ndb.UserProperty(auto_current_user=True)
    updated_on = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

This should cause the `auto_` properties to be triggered automatically.

Comment: Hi Brent, this is where I'm coming from. I already had that flat class model in place. I switched because I wanted to maintain those special fields in  one place and because I want to give the JSON more structure (like mentioned at [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org)). Beside those 'sys'-fields I do also have got 'value'-fields and 'acl'-fields which follow the same structure, but they do not have got any auto-fields. I didn't think of performance yet, is the response time more than 20% longer than with a flat model?

Comment: I haven't used StructuredProperty for a while and the performance may have changed, but when I tried using them I found the response times to be significantly slower.  The best thing for you to do is to create both kinds of models and fill them with data, and then test response times for queries.